# NodeJs Cannot Find Module. Path and name are correct

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to debug a simple error in NodeJs. Error: Cannot find module './schema/schema'.
I tried to create a dummy file with a string and trying to require in my project root and the same error showed up. I tried to delete the folder and the file about 3x and the error persist.
Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const expressGraphQL = require('express-graphql').graphqlHTTP;

const schema = require('./schema/schema');

const app = express();

app.use('/graphql', expressGraphQL({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: true
}));

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Listening');
});
```

My schema file

```
const graphql = require('axios');
const axios = require('axios');

const {
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLString,
    GraphQLInt,
    GraphQLSchema,
} = graphql

const CompanyType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Company',
    fields: {
        id: { type: GraphQLString },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        description: { type: GraphQLString }
    }
});

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    fields: {
        id: { type: GraphQLString},
        firstName: { type: GraphQLString },
        age: { type: GraphQLInt },
        company: {
            type: CompanyType,
            resolve(parentValue, args) {
                axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/companies/${parentValue.companyId}`).then(
                    (response) => response.data
                );
            }
        }
    }
});

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        user: {
            type: UserType,
            args: { id: { type: GraphQLString } },
            resolve(parentValue, args) {
                return axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/users/${args.id}`).then(
                    (response) => response.data
                );
            }
        },
        company: {
            type: CompanyType,
            args: { id: { type: GraphQLString } },
            resolve(parentValue, args) {
                return axios.get(`https://localhost:3000/companies/${args.id}`).then(
                    (response) => response.data
                );
            }
        }
    }
});

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: RootQuery
});
```

How my project is organised:

[image]

I tried to clone this project in another machine and the error persist. Does anyone have a clue about this? There are no typos, no spaces in the file, also I tried to delete node modules and run `yarn` and no success.

Comment: Both answers are correct. I generated the `tsconfig.json` and I had to use the command `ts-node server.ts`. I'm new to Ts in Node, I always used with JS.Plus I had to change the `schema.ts` to `export default new GraphQLSchema`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your files have a `.ts` extension.

It can't find the file because it doesn't have a `.js` or `.cjs` file extension.

If you're using TypeScript, then use:

- `import`/`export` and not `require`/`modules.exports` *and*
- a typescript compiler

If you're not using TypeScript then use a `.js` file extension.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is:

```
import sampleModule = require('modulename');
```

or

```
import * as sampleModule from 'modulename';
```

Then compile your TypeScript with --module commonjs.